# Bacula versions compatibility

Tags: backup, bacula

Recently we have upgraded some of our servers to `Ubuntu 16.04` and `Bacula file daemon` has also been upgraded to `version 7.0.5`.

Now we have:

- `Bacula director v5.2.6 (on Ubuntu 14.04)`
- `storage daemons v5.2.6 (on Ubuntu 14.04)`
- some `file daemons v5.2.6 (on Ubuntu 14.04)`
- some `file daemons v7.0.5 (on Ubuntu 16.04)`.

Now `Bacula` gives this error on the machines with Ubuntu 16.04 and `Bacula file daemon v7.0.5`:

> Fatal error: Bad response to Storage command: wanted 2000 OK storage

I didn't find anything about version incompatibility(Newer file daemons with older Director and Storage daemons) [here](http://wiki.bacula.org/doku.php?id=versions_compatibility).

Downgrading `Bacula fd to v5.2.6 on Ubuntu 16.04` would also be a solution for me if there is a way to do this.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved after upgrading storage daemons to v7.0.5.
We still have some file daemons v5.2.6.

Comment: This looks like a FAQ from the bacula-users mailing list, see https://sourceforge.net/p/bacula/mailman/message/35303587/ or https://sourceforge.net/p/bacula/mailman/message/32505228/

Answer (score 0):

Try to check connection parameters - i.e. valid host and port configuration on both sides.

The error message you see can also mean: "Protocol violation" when you connect to wrong service.

Bacula (and Bareos) developers tries hardly to make SD and directors compatible with older FDs (with some newer features not working, of course). Only your director and storage daemon should be of same version.

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed Bacula ans some clients on differents debians with differents versions of the FD.

My director :

```
*version    
sbacula-dir Version: 7.4.4 (28 September 2016) x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu debian 8.7
```

A client :

```
    *status client=s1-fd
    Connecting to Client s1-fd at <IP>:9102
    s1-fd Version: 7.4.4 (28 September 2016)  x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu debian 7.11
```

other client :

```
*status client=s2-fd
Connecting to Client s2-fd at <IP>:9102

s2-fd Version: 5.2.6 (21 February 2012)  x86_64-pc-linux-gnu debian jessie/sid
```

And all works fine.

During the install, I'd got the same fatal error and it was a problem in my DNS resolution. Maybe you have the same problem of accessibility (DNS, firewall,routing,vlan,...).